# Merging by column in deedle

Tags: .net, merge, deedle

I have two data sets:

- Data1 columns:  `Name, column2, column3`
- Data2 columns:  `Name, some_column2 ...`

How can I merge by column "Name"?

It seems that Deedle can only merge by index key.  In that case, how can I change my "int" type index to use "Name" column?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is right - you'll need to use the name as the index of both of the data frames and then use the `Merge` operation. For this to work, the names also need to be unique. If you have non-unique names, then you might need to do this on a grouped frame.

For example, given the following two data frames:

```
let df1 = 
  Frame.ofRowsOrdinal [
    series [ "name" => "Tomas"; "city" => "London" ]
  ]

let df2 = 
  Frame.ofRowsOrdinal [
    series [ "name" => "Tomas"; "twitter" => "@tomaspetricek" ]
  ]
```

You can reindex and merge them as follows - this is in F#, but the same should work from C#:

```
let df1ByName = df1.IndexRows<string>("name")
let df2ByName = df2.IndexRows<string>("name")
let merged = df1ByName.Merge(df2ByName)
```